# Mice package in a time-series analysis

Tags: r, time-series, r-mice

```
 newdata <- mice(data = newdata, m = 5, method = "pmm", seed = 500)

iter imp variable
  1   1  1996-01-31Error in terms.formula(tmp, simplify = TRUE) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

Comment: Have you tried to use md.pattern to get a better understanding of your missing data? It is hard to know what exactly has gone wrong without a reproducible data/command. Perhaps you can add more by adding some details about the data.